# i am trying to create a 925x902 grid at 0.005 precision and it is very time consuming, how can it be sped up?

Tags: python

this is the main body code and is there any way of speeding it up as it takes almost all day to produce an output file

```
from landlab import RasterModelGrid


mg=RasterModelGrid((925,902),0.005) 


from landlab.io import read_esri_ascii
(mg, z) = read_esri_ascii('dem46.txt', name="topographic__elevation")

mg.set_closed_boundaries_at_grid_edges(True, False, True, False)

from terrainbento import Clock, Basic
clock = Clock(start=13800, stop=21300, step=1500)  
#time step 25 mins from dem46 to dem71

model = Basic(clock, mg)
model.run_one_step(1500)
mg.save('dem46.nc')
```

Comment: This code doesn't entirely make sense - you create `mg` as a `RasterModelGrid` (with 33 billion grid points, if I'm interpreting the parameters correctly), but then immediately overwrite it in the line `(mg, z) = read_esri_ascii(...)`.  I don't know if creating the grid takes a significant amount of time, but it's completely wasted effort.

Comment: Thank you, I am struggling to write this code with very limited knowledge of python. If do not create the grid and run the code from then on would it work in theory? What else is obvious and would need to be changed?